# Singlerun unit test Angular 5

Tags: angular

I'm creating an SDK image on docker for my Angular 5 application. With the migration from version 4 to version 5 of Angular

```
--singleRun
```

flag does not work. I tried using

```
--watch=false
```

but it did not work either on docker. Is there any other way I can force the unit tests to run only once?

Answer (score 0):

Its `--single-run` or `--no-single-run` as mentioned in [Karma Configurations](http://karma-runner.github.io/2.0/config/configuration-file.html).
If you want, you can use `singleRun: true` in `karma.conf.js` as well.